# Comparing HashMap Integer with arrayList int somehow does not allways work

Tags: java

as you can see from the title, I am trying to compare the key of a HashMap to a int from an ArrayList.
For the first 47 compares, 38 = 38, but on the 48 comparasion, 38 != 38. Can you help me with that?

```
`@Override
public HashMap<Integer, Integer> populate(int roomId){
    ArrayList<Item> original = items.populateTable(roomId);
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> refined = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 1; i < original.size(); i++){
        Iterator it = refined.entrySet().iterator();
        refined.put(original.get(0).getStockId(), 1); // put the first item in the hashMap
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            if( pair.getKey().equals( original.get(i).getStockId() ) ) //if item is not in hashMap
            {
                System.out.println(pair.getKey()+"++");
                refined.put(original.get(i).getStockId(), refined.get(original.get(i).getStockId()) + 1); //increment the value
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("NEW:"+pair.getKey());
                refined.put(original.get(i).getStockId(), 1); // add it to hashMap
            }
        }
    }
    Iterator it1 = refined.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it1.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry pair1 = (Map.Entry)it1.next();
        System.out.println(pair1.getKey() + " = " + pair1.getValue());
    }

    return refined;
}`
```

[and this is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeVtv.png)

Comment: post the code as text not as image

Comment: Present the relevant code *in the question itself*.  Moreover, present it *as text*, not as an image.  No, we will not look at images on an external server.

Comment: Start with using `.equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: Did you mean to skip `i == 0`?

Comment: @criket_007 Yes, I want the first item to be put in the HashMap. Then I skip it because I dont want to count it twice.

Comment: Don't change the structure of a collection while you have an iterator open on it, except through the iterator itself.

Comment: Put, you should put `refined.put(original.get(0).getStockId(), 1);` before the loop, then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are solving problem to count all numbers encountered in array, if its a case, you do it wrong. In iteration where 38!=38 ('New: 38' in console) its not a 38 any more, it compares 38 and 39, thats why next line is '39++'.

Here what probably you want to do.

```
ArrayList<Item> original = items.populateTable(roomId);
HashMap<Integer, Integer> refined = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++){
    int key = original.get(i).getStockId();
    int count = refined.containsKey(key) ? refined.get(key) : 0;
    refined.put(key, count + 1);
}
Iterator it1 = refined.entrySet().iterator();
while(it1.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry pair1 = (Map.Entry)it1.next();
    System.out.println(pair1.getKey() + " = " + pair1.getValue());
}
```

With input 38, 38, 38, 39, 39

Produces
38 = 3
39 = 2

Comment: Could use `for (Item key : original)` here

Comment: sure, i used authors original code, and changed only main part, thanks